# Split worksheets into multiple files and skip hidden files

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code. It splits the sheets in an Excel workbook then saves each sheet as it's own book.

It fails if there are hidden sheets in the workbooks.

Here is the code:

```
Sub SplitWorkbook()
'Updateby20140612
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim FolderName As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook
DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
FolderName = xWb.Path & "\" & xWb.Name & " " & DateString
MkDir FolderName
For Each xWs In xWb.Worksheets
    xWs.Copy
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        Select Case xWb.FileFormat
            Case 51:
                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If Application.ActiveWorkbook.HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56:
                FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else:
                FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
        End Select
    End If
    xFile = FolderName & "\" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & FileExtStr
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

So if someone hid sheets, the VBA will fail.

Currently the VBA will save the new workbook as the sheet name, but it would be ideal if I could get the code to append the old workbook 'XXX' in front of the new name "XXX_new name".

Answer (score 0):

Original source: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win007.htm

```
Sub Copy_Every_Sheet_To_New_Workbook()
'Working in 97-2013
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DateString As String
    Dim FolderName As String

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    'Copy every sheet from the workbook with this macro
    Set Sourcewb = ThisWorkbook

    'Create new folder to save the new files in
    DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
    FolderName = Sourcewb.Path & "\" & Sourcewb.Name & " " & DateString
    MkDir FolderName

    'Copy every visible sheet to a new workbook
    For Each sh In Sourcewb.Worksheets

        'If the sheet is visible then copy it to a new workbook
        If sh.Visible = -1 Then
            sh.Copy

            'Set Destwb to the new workbook
            Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

            'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
            With Destwb
                If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
                    'You use Excel 97-2003
                    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
                Else
                    'You use Excel 2007-2013
                    If Sourcewb.Name = .Name Then
                        MsgBox "Your answer is NO in the security dialog"
                        GoTo GoToNextSheet
                    Else
                        Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
                        Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                        Case 52:
                            If .HasVBProject Then
                                FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                            Else
                                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                            End If
                        Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
                        Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
                        End Select
                    End If
                End If
            End With


            'Save the new workbook and close it
            With Destwb
                .SaveAs FolderName _
                      & "\" & Destwb.Sheets(1).Name & FileExtStr, _
                        FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
                .Close False
            End With

        End If
GoToNextSheet:
    Next sh

    MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```